# How implement random access iterator for sequence of element, which less 1 byte?

Tags: c++11, iterator, random-access

How to implement a random access iterator for a sequence of elements which less than a single byte? For example, 6 bits.

Code example to illustrate what I want:

```
template<typename T>
class val_iterator : std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T>
{
    // ???
};

template<typename T>
class val_container
{
    void *_data;
public:
    val_container(void *data): _data(data) {}
    // ???
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned int> vec =
    {
        0xA, // '00 1010'
        0xE, // '00 1110'
        0x1F,// '01 1111'
        0x3F // '11 1111'
    };

    // 4 elements of 6 bits
    const size_t byte_count = 4 * 6 / 8;

    std::array<unsigned char, byte_count> bytes;
    val_container<unsigned char> values(bytes.data());

    val_iterator<unsigned char> val_it = values.begin();
    for(auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it, ++val_it)
        *val_it = (unsigned char) *it;

    // elements:
    // '00 1010'_'00 1110'_'01 1111'_'11 1111'
    // bytes in memory:
    // '0010 1000'_'1110 0111'_'1111 1111'
    assert(bytes[0] == 0x28);  // '0010 1000'
    assert(bytes[1] == 0xE7);  // '1110 0111'
    assert(bytes[1] == 0xFF);  // '1111 1111'

    assert(values[0] == 0xA);  // '00 1010'
    assert(values[1] == 0xE);  // '00 1110'
    assert(values[2] == 0x1F); // '01 1111'
    assert(values[3] == 0x3F); // '11 1111'
    return 0;
}
```

Or it is not random access iterator, but another category of iterators?

I also think that this byte sequence consists of repeating blocks of three bytes each, which store 4 elements each. Maybe it knowledge can be used in an iterator, but I don't know how, yet.

EDIT:
I was not right about the location of bits in the byte array. In little-endian bits will looks like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4DcQ.png)

And, I try to implement this iterator/container. I used this [code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113957/random-access-iterator-for-custom-data-type-in-c) for start, and implementation of `std::vector<bool>` to write reference of value.

```
template<size_t TBitCount, typename TDataType, typename TValueType>
struct val_help
{
    static size_t vals_count_in_block;
    static size_t bytes_count_in_block;
    static TValueType max_value;

    static bool init()
    {
        static bool inited = false;
        if(inited)
            return true;

        constexpr size_t value_size_in_bits = sizeof(TValueType) * 8;
        static_assert(TBitCount >= 1, "TBitCount must be at least 1 bit");
        static_assert(TBitCount <= value_size_in_bits, "TValueType doesn't have enough bit");
        static_assert(sizeof(TDataType) == 1, "sizeof TDataType must be 1 byte");

        size_t bits = 0;
        size_t data_size_in_bits = sizeof(TDataType) * 8;
        do {
            vals_count_in_block++;
            bits += TBitCount;
        } while (bits % data_size_in_bits != 0);

        bytes_count_in_block = bits / 8;

        inited = true;
        return true;
    }

    static size_t get_byte_idx(size_t val_idx)
    {
        return val_idx * bytes_count_in_block / vals_count_in_block;
    }

    static size_t get_lo_shift(size_t val_idx)
    {
        return (val_idx * TBitCount) % 8;
    }
};

template<size_t TBitCount, typename TDataType, typename TValueType>
size_t val_help<TBitCount, TDataType, TValueType>::vals_count_in_block = 0;

template<size_t TBitCount, typename TDataType, typename TValueType>
size_t val_help<TBitCount, TDataType, TValueType>::bytes_count_in_block = 0;

template<size_t TBitCount, typename TDataType, typename TValueType>
TValueType val_help<TBitCount, TDataType, TValueType>::max_value = (1 << TBitCount) - 1;

template<size_t TBitCount, typename TDataType, typename TValueType>
class val_reference
{
    using h = val_help<TBitCount, TDataType, TValueType>;
    TDataType* _data;
    size_t _val_idx;

public:
    val_reference() : _data(nullptr), _val_idx(0) {}
    val_reference(TDataType* data, size_t val_idx) : _data(data), _val_idx(val_idx) {}

    operator TValueType() const
    { return get_value(); }

    val_reference& operator=(TValueType val)
    {
        set_value(val);
        return *this;
    }

    val_reference& operator=(const val_reference rhs) const
    { return *this = TValueType(rhs); }

    bool operator==(const val_reference rhs) const
    { return TValueType(*this) == TValueType(rhs); }

    bool operator<(const val_reference rhs) const
    { return TValueType(*this) < TValueType(rhs); }

    // ToDo other operation

    size_t idx() const
    { return _val_idx; }
private:

    TValueType get_value() const
    {
        size_t byte_idx = h::get_byte_idx(_val_idx);
        auto ptr_to_val = reinterpret_cast<TValueType*>(_data + byte_idx);
        size_t lo_shift = h::get_lo_shift(_val_idx);
        size_t hi_shift = sizeof(TValueType) * 8 - lo_shift;

        bool is_hi_valid = byte_idx + sizeof(TValueType) < h::bytes_count_in_block;
        auto lo = *ptr_to_val >> lo_shift;
        auto hi = is_hi_valid ? *(ptr_to_val + 1) << hi_shift : 0;

        return (hi | lo) & h::max_value;
    }

    void set_value(TValueType value)
    {
        auto val = value & h::max_value;

        size_t byte_idx = h::get_byte_idx(_val_idx);
        auto ptr_to_val = reinterpret_cast<TValueType*>(_data + byte_idx);
        size_t lo_shift = h::get_lo_shift(_val_idx);
        size_t hi_shift = sizeof(TValueType) * 8 - lo_shift;

        TValueType &lo = *ptr_to_val;
        lo = (lo & ~(h::max_value << lo_shift)) | (val << lo_shift);

        bool is_hi_valid = byte_idx + sizeof(TValueType) < h::bytes_count_in_block;
        if(is_hi_valid)
        {
            TValueType &hi = *(ptr_to_val + 1);
            hi = (hi & ~(h::max_value >> hi_shift)) | (val >> hi_shift);
        }
    }
};

template<size_t TBitCount, typename TDataType, typename TValueType>
class val_iterator : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, TValueType>
{
    using h = val_help<TBitCount, TDataType, TValueType>;
    TDataType *_data;
    size_t _val_idx;

public:
    using reference = val_reference<TBitCount, TDataType, TValueType>;
    using pointer = val_reference<TBitCount, TDataType, TValueType>*;
    using iterator = val_iterator<TBitCount, TDataType, TValueType>;
    using difference_type = int;

    val_iterator(TDataType* data) : _data(data), _val_idx(0){}
    val_iterator(TDataType* data, unsigned int val_idx) : _data(data), _val_idx(val_idx){}
    val_iterator(const iterator& rhs) : _data(rhs._data), _val_idx(rhs._val_idx) {}

    iterator& operator=(const iterator& rhs)
    {
        _data = rhs._data;
        _val_idx = rhs._val_idx;
        return *this;
    }

    reference operator*() const
    { return reference(_data, _val_idx); }

    reference operator[](const difference_type& n) const
    { return *(*this + n); }

    iterator& operator++()
    {
        if(_val_idx == h::vals_count_in_block - 1)
        {
            _data += h::bytes_count_in_block;
            _val_idx = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ++_val_idx;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    iterator& operator--()
    {
        if(_val_idx == 0)
        {
            _data -= h::bytes_count_in_block;
            _val_idx = h::vals_count_in_block - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            --_val_idx;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    iterator operator++(int)
    {
        iterator tmp(*this);
        ++(*this);
        return tmp;
    }

    iterator operator--(int)
    {
        iterator tmp(*this);
        --(*this);
        return tmp;
    }

    iterator& operator+=(const difference_type& n)
    {
        auto idx = _val_idx + n;
        _data += (idx / h::vals_count_in_block) * h::bytes_count_in_block;
        _val_idx = idx % h::vals_count_in_block;
        return *this;
    }

    iterator operator+(const difference_type& n) const
    {
        iterator tmp(*this);
        tmp += n;
        return tmp;
    }

    iterator& operator-=(const difference_type& n)
    {
        if(n <= _val_idx)
        {
            _val_idx -= n;
            return *this;
        }

        auto diff_idx = (n % h::vals_count_in_block) - _val_idx;
        auto idx = n - diff_idx;
        _data -= (idx / h::vals_count_in_block + 1) * h::bytes_count_in_block;
        _val_idx = h::vals_count_in_block - diff_idx;
        return *this;
    }

    iterator operator-(const difference_type& n) const
    {
        iterator tmp(*this);
        tmp -= n;
        return tmp;
    }

    bool operator==(const iterator& rhs) const
    {
        return _data == rhs._data && _val_idx == rhs._val_idx;
    }

    bool operator!=(const iterator& rhs) const
    {
        return !(*this == rhs);
    }

    bool operator<(const iterator& rhs) const
    {
        return _data == rhs._data
            ? _val_idx < rhs._val_idx
            : _data < rhs._data;
    }

    bool operator<=(const iterator& rhs) const
    {
        return *this < rhs || *this == rhs;
    }

    bool operator>(const iterator& rhs) const
    {
        return !(*this <= rhs);
    }

    bool operator>=(const iterator& rhs) const
    {
        return !(*this < rhs);
    }
};

template<size_t TBitCount, typename TDataType, typename TValueType,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<TValueType>::value, int>::type = 0>
class val_container
{
    using h = val_help<TBitCount, TDataType, TValueType>;
    TDataType* _data;
    size_t _size;

public:
    using value_type = TValueType;
    using size_type = size_t;
    using difference_type = int;
    using reference = val_reference<TBitCount, TDataType, TValueType>;
    using const_reference = TValueType;
    using pointer = val_reference<TBitCount, TDataType, TValueType>*;
    using const_pointer = const TValueType*;
    using iterator = val_iterator<TBitCount, TDataType, TValueType>;
    using const_iterator = val_iterator<TBitCount, TDataType, const TValueType>;

    val_container(TDataType* data = nullptr, size_t size = 0) : _data(data), _size(size)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof(TDataType) == 1, "sizeof TDataType must be 1 byte");
        static_assert(TBitCount >= 1, "TBitCount must be at least 1 bit");

        static volatile bool s = h::init();

        if(size % h::bytes_count_in_block != 0)
            throw std::invalid_argument(std::string("size: ") +  std::to_string(size)+ " % " + std::to_string(h::bytes_count_in_block) + " != 0");
    }
    val_container(TDataType& data, size_t size) : val_container(&data, size) {}

    iterator begin()
    { return iterator(_data); }

    const_iterator begin() const
    { return const_iterator(_data); }

    const_iterator cbegin() const
    { return const_iterator(_data); }

    iterator end()
    { return iterator(_data + _size); }

    const_iterator end() const
    { return const_iterator(_data + _size); }

    const_iterator cend() const
    { return const_iterator(_data + _size); }

    size_type size() const
    { return _size; }

    bool empty() const
    { return begin() == end(); }

    reference operator[](size_type n)
    { return *(iterator(_data) + n); }

    const_reference operator[](size_type n) const
    { return *(const_iterator(_data) + n); }
};
```

It work for any TBitCount (I think).
What can be improved in this code?

Comment: You may want to read about how `vector<bool>` specialization is defined (as example, it works with single bits inside a byte). You can make iterators/subscript operator that return the proxy objects which in turn access less than byte sequences. Also please add some info about _why_ do you need it? Compacting can lead to decreased performance.

Comment: In this format packed data comes from the device. I want to iterate data with the val_iterator, decoding the values, for example, into a vector <unsigned int>. The question describes the reverse situation of unpacking, so that it was to simple illustrate what I want

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to implement a random access iterator in general, you need to implement the operations that are required to fulfill the RandomAccessIterator concept.

You will need to implement addition and subtraction with integers and compound assignment for each, subtraction of two iterators, subscript operator, less/greather than operator, both strict and non-strict, (in-)equality operator, pre- and post-increment and -decrement, dereference and the arrow operator.

See the documentation of iterator concepts for exact required behaviour for each of those operations.

---

Secondly, you must consider the fact that the elements returned by the iterator are less than byte sized. Clearly, since a byte is the smallest addressable object, you cannot have a reference to such smaller object (or rather, such fragments of objects).

What you can do is use a custom proxy class as your `val_iterator::reference`. The behaviour of the proxy should be to modify the referenced bits when assigned to, and be implicitly convertible to the value of the referenced bit range. This is the same way the `std::vector<bool>::reference` is implemented.

Comment: Thx, I will try to do it

Comment: Random Access Iterators are a form of BiDirectionalIterators which are a form of ForwardIterators.  ForwardIterators **must** have a `reference` type that is **an actual reference**; they may not use proxy references.  `std::vector<bool>::iterator` **is not a random access iterator** as defined by the standard.

Comment: @Yakk good point, I had not realized that. This iterator will have to settle for similar status of almost a RandomAccessIterator but not quite. Would it be wrong then to use the `std::random_access_iterator_tag` or is it OK?